# LINQ Count null values

Tags: c#, linq, count, nul

I'm doing a simple Pie chart that counts current employee, I'm still new to LINQ so I just want to ask is there a way to total count null values?

Here's my code so far:

```
public ActionResult PieCount()
{    
    int undefined = db.EMPs.Where(x => x.JS_REF == 1).Count();
    int regular = db.EMPs.Where(x => x.JS_REF ==2 ).Count();
    int contractual = db.EMPs.Where(x => x.JS_REF == 3).Count();
    int probationary = db.EMPs.Where(x => x.JS_REF ==4 ).Count();
    int notdefined = db.EMPs.Where(x => x.JS_REF == null ).Count();

    Ratio obj = new Ratio();

    obj.Undefined = undefined;
    obj.Contractual = contractual;
    obj.Regular = regular;
    obj.Probationary = probationary;
    obj.Notdefined = notdefined;

    return Json(new { result = obj }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

It's working so far but when I tried to count null value "x.JS_REF == null" I'm getting an error

here's the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xdQg.png)

My database:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bh066.png)

Comment: Please show us your error message as well.

Comment: the null value count is valid, so the issue you're having is likely something else. what's the error?

Comment: I just noticed I forgot to add a comma

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a predicate to your `Count()` expression

```
int notdefined = db.EMPs.Count(x => x.JS_REF == 0);
```

or

```
int notdefined = db.EMPs.Count(x => String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.JS_REF.ToString()) == null);
```

Note that:  `int` cannot be null. If a value is not set to it, then the default value I believe is zero. So you should check your type of `JS_REF` is `int` or `int?`

---

**Refactor code**

You should get all data at one time then count from them instead of calling multiple times.

```
var data = db.EMPs.Where(x => 0 <= x.JS_REF && x.JS_REF <= 4).Select(p => p.JS_REF ).ToList();

int undefined = data.Count(x => x == 1);
int regular = ddata.Count(x => x == 2);
int contractual = data.Count(x => x == 3);
int probationary = data.Count(x => x == 4);
int notdefined = data.Count(x => x == 0);
```